# Adding connection strings to a production app

Tags: reactjs, production

I have an app ready for production. For it to work, each client needs to set a unique url to access their data. How would i prepare the app for making it easy to add a url as an access point to the clients?

Would a correct way to do this be to add it in the manifest.json file and somehow reference it from there? (Until now in development i've only used a global URL in a js file)

Comment: A `.env` environment file or a `aoo-config.js` will help you here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the package [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and create a `.env` file in your root directory which should contain your environment variables.

Assuming that the URl you are referring to is `http://localhost:3000/some/url` on your localhost, then your `.env` file might look like:

```
MY_URL=http://localhost:3000/some/url
```

Then in your react application, you can get the value of `MY_URL` by doing:

```
const url = process.env.MY_URL
```

Note that if you are using the [create-react-app package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app), then you do not need to install the [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) since it already comes with the [create-react-app package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app). Also you need to change it:

```
REACT_APP_MY_URL=http://localhost:3000/some/url
```

Also make sure to add the `.env` file to your `.gitignore` file so that you do not push it to your repo.

Assuming that you are deploying your application to Heroku. Heroku provides a simple interface which allows you to add your environment variables which looks like:

[image]

That's it.

Comment: This would work if i only had to declare the variable at build time, but i need this to work at runtime

Comment: Not true, this will work both at build time or runtime. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: I have a unejected create-react-app with a .env pointing to a location. I then do a 'npm run build' and get a bunch of files produced in the build folder. Then i run 'serve -s build'. And here is my problem - as i do not know the actual url the app will be using, i have to inject it into the app at a later stage. Currently it points to the url used in development, but this needs to be changed. How would i do that? I tried creating a new .env file in build folder, but no luck

Comment: Which platform are you deploying your app to?

Comment: Also you don't need to create a new .env file in the build folder. Note that when you run `npm run build`, `process.env.MY_URL` will be replaced by `http://localhost:3000/some/url` in your build files

Comment: it will also be very helpful if you can show us your code.

Comment: deploying to azure, and run with IIS server. How we would like this to work is to hand over a generic codebase to the client, then provide some easy "here-is-how-you-connect-the-app-to-your-database" instructions, ideally just copy pasting a string in a file in order to set it up. We cannot assume they have any technical knowhow. Obviously node reads the .env file whenever it boots up the app in development and uses this to connect, i was hoping there is a similar way to do this whenever a server (not necessarily node) starts the app, but im starting to fear it is not that easy...

Comment: So you can start by renaming the .env file to env.sample which will contain dummy data is can be pushed to your repo. In your `here-is-how-you-connect-the-app-to-your-database` file, let the user know that they need to replace the dummy values with the appropriate values and add them to Azure. You can check how to set environment variables on Azure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could store them in [environment variables](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)?

that way you can always edit them later without having to change components.